# c++ repaint part of window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, gdi+

i know how to repaint the full window but i don't know how to repaint a pieace of window like i draw a squre using gdi+ than i want to change it's coordinates so i want to repaint the squre not the whole window 
anyidea?

---

i also tried this

```
RECT rect2;
rect2.left=0;
rect2.top=100;
rect2.right=225;
rect2.bottom=300;
InvadiateRect(hwnd, &rect2, false);
```

it still repaint the whole window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to call `InvalidateRect()` with a rectangle that is large enough to cover *both* the old and new positions of the square you moved. Windows will then call your `WM_PAINT` handler to repaint the area of the screen that changed.

The [`UnionRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145163(VS.85).aspx) function is helpful for calculating this repaint rectangle.

Comment: i tried wat you suggested me but didn't reall work. i created a rect structure with x and y coordinates but still repaint the whole window

Comment: When you call `BeginPaint()`, you get back a `PAINTSTRUCT` structure that contains a `rcPaint` member. You can limit the amount of your window that you paint by looking at `rcPaint` in your `WM_PAINT` handler.