# c++ repaint part of window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, window

i want to repaint part of the window not the whole thing. i have no idea how to. im using win32 please no mfc........
thanks in advance

---

```
// create rect structure
RECT rect2;
rect2.left=0;
rect2.top=0;
rect2.right=225;
rect2.bottom=300;
// calling invalidateRect when left mouse button is donw
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect2, false);
    break;
```

Comment: Simple answer: don't use GDI for games. No matter how careful you are to minimize work on your redraws, OpenGL or DirectX is virtually *certain* to do a lot better job.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Actually there are still good reasons to use GDI for some games. If performance is less important that portability to very old systems or systems with outdated graphics card drivers, or if you are blitting 2D in software anyway, GDI is still a viable choice. For instance, I've created a for casual games game engine based entirely on GDI, but also optimized to run decently for many scenarios commonly seen in casual games.

Comment: @Adrian: If you're happy with it, that's great. While compatibility with older hardware/software carries some restrictions, I use OpenGL  quite successfully under NT 3.5 on hardware so old you can hardly find it outside a museum any more.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Yes, but if your software is very widely spread there will always be users with buggy and / or outdated graphics card drivers. Using GDI instead of OpenGL lets you get around this with very little hassle. Popcap's game engine also uses a GDI fallback mode for the same reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ repaint part of window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562051/c-repaint-part-of-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the rectangle of the portion of window, which you want to re-paint, in InvalidateRect() method. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: i already thought of that but it didn't work you can see my code ill post it in minute

Comment: Define "didn't work". Also, if you have your own WM_PAINT handler, then you need to respect the clip rectangle it gives you. In general though, if this is for a game, as mentioned, you're most likely better off with DirectX if you're planning to do more than simple blitting and shapes.

Comment: all im using gdi for is to draw a simple rectangle and to load some images

Answer (score 2):

Is this for a game engine? It appears so since you are concerned about cpu usage on a full redraw.

If it is, then I'd recommend blitting  to a back buffer image, keeping track of what portion of your back buffer has changed and copying only that portion to the screen once you are done rendering. This is called double buffering and will also take care of flickering issues you might see.

Comment: yes im creating a game and im also using double buffering in my game

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28VS.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: if i redraw the whole window it will use too much of my cpu

Comment: `RedrawWindow` redraws **part** of a window. Check `lprcUpdate` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out; when handling WM_PAINT you need to get the update rectangle/region and draw/blit accordingly.

see:
+ [The WM_PAINT Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145137(VS.85).aspx)
+ [Retrieving the Update Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162936(v=VS.85).aspx)
+ [Invalidating and Validating the Update Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145004(v=VS.85).aspx)
+ [Synchronous and Asynchronous Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145126(v=VS.85).aspx)